# Интерполяция точек данных в Excel

Tags: excel, интерполяция

Всем привет!

Имеется таблица с исходными точками (Х и У), по которым строим график.

[image: Точки построения исходного графика]

Дальше мы отбираем пробы, и получаем только У значения

[image: Полученные Х значения]

Необходимо вычислить значения Х на исходном графике для новых значений У. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать? Спасибо

[image: Исходный график]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если график строить наоборот, по оси x - мВ, по оси y - %. Тогда мы получим заивисмость %(мВ), можем показать уравнение (на примере я взял тренд полиноминальный, степень 4) и подставив в это уравнение нужные вам мВ получить %

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это если копировать уравнение интерполяции. Если надо полностью автоматически, то можно тоже самое сделать через поиск решения (но должна быть включена надстройка "поиск решения" и определиться с формулой интерполяции)

Comment: Хм....значения в пробах 991 и 992 схожи с теми, что я получил на миллиметровке. Можно Вас попросить скинуть файлик? К примеру на почту, если тут никак: `nicolay92@mail.ru`

Comment: Так все данные ваши, просто меняете местами % и мВ и строите диаграмму, добавляете линию тренда, отмечаете галочку - показывать уравнение и это уравнение вставляете где вы хотите считать свои %, на скриншоте для ячейки D10 формула видна вверху-справа скриншота, она просто скопирована из уравнения и исправлена согласно правил екселя, файл выслал, там тоже самое что и тут

Comment: А если не менять местами столбцы?